# Retrieve Zoho Mail using Zoho CRM API

Tags: crm, zoho

We have connected our Zoho Mail with Zoho CRM using IMAP configuration. Now we are able to see the emails on Contact's Email section.

Is there a way to get these emails via Zoho CRM API? Similar to how we get Notes/Events for a contact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on Zoho CRM we don't have any functions or API's available to fetch mail sent from CRM. But using Zoho mail API's we can fetch the required information. Also kindly check Zoho integration tasks. But on CRM we don't have any methods by default to get those details. Mail sent to one particular lead record can be obtained user get search mail api kindly refer Zoho mail API. As you mentioned Zoho mail and CRM and integrated, in such cases you can contact Zoho CRM team requesting to provide API to get only those mail which is associated with a particular contact

FYI please find the link :

Zoho Mail API: https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/api/get-search-emails.html

ZOHO Integration Task Methods: https://www.zoho.com/deluge/help/script/mail/get-details.html

If I know what exactly you are looking for I can suggest you better